# How to test ApplicationData.Current.DataChanged

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a windows store app, I want to test roaming settings, I developed my app using vs2012 on one of my machine, and installed the app using powershell on another machine, then changed the roaming settings, but nothing happend. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the application installed on two machines, when you change the roaming settings one machine it will eventually propagate to other machine.

To test this, debug both applications simultaneously and place a breakpoint inside the event you attached to ApplicationData.DataChanged (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.datachanged)

Now when you change the roaming settings inside one the applications, the application on the other machine should break when it receives the data.

Be aware that for normal roaming settings it can take anywhere from 5-15 minutes, or longer in some cases. For testing, it is easier to send high priority data - this should take much less time, hopefully less than a minute.